# Solana start solana-test-validator on Linux / Ubuntu blockstore error

Tags: solana, solana-cli

When trying to start the `solana-test-validator` on my Ubuntu machine I received the following error:

```
Error: failed to start validator: Failed to create ledger at test-ledger: blockstore error
```

When taking a detailed look at the error logs I noticed the following issue:

```
[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2021-12-11T10:29:28.942979023Z [0m[1m[31mERROR[0m solana_ledger::blockstore[0m[38;5;8m][0m tar stderr: /bin/sh: 1: bzip2: not found
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue can be fixed by installing `bzip2`.
The following line should fix the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install bzip2
```