# Getting 'blockstore error' when running test validator for solana

Tags: blockchain, bzip2, solana, solana-cli, solana-web3js

On running the command `solana-test-validator` on a Windows system, I get the error:

```
[2022-01-06T06:54:41.602352800Z INFO  solana_test_validator] solana-validator 1.9.0 (src:7782d34b; feat:378846963)
[2022-01-06T06:54:41.602479300Z INFO  solana_test_validator] Starting validator with: ArgsOs {
        inner: [
            "solana-test-validator",
        ],
    }
[2022-01-06T06:54:41.602617400Z WARN  solana_perf] CUDA is disabled
[2022-01-06T06:54:41.602720300Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX detected
[2022-01-06T06:54:41.602823600Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX2 detected
[2022-01-06T06:54:41.606436300Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet] Faucet started. Listening on: 0.0.0.0:9900
[2022-01-06T06:54:41.606635600Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet] Faucet account address: 2P4mpwfirxqrL3naJD7C5UHYynPgVugaRu9sBT6m73EZ
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger\validator.log
⠁
⠉ Initializing...
[2022-01-06T06:54:44.975790700Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] "test-ledger\\rocksdb" open took 3.3s
[2022-01-06T06:54:44.981740300Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] metrics disabled: SOLANA_METRICS_CONFIG: environment variable not found
[2022-01-06T06:54:44.982273700Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: shred_insert_is_full total_time_ms=0i slot=0i ⠒ Initializing...
[2022-01-06T06:54:45.595853800Z ERROR solana_ledger::blockstore] tar stdout:
[2022-01-06T06:54:45.596099200Z ERROR solana_ledger::blockstore] tar stderr: tar: Can't launch external program: bzip2
Error: failed to start validator: Failed to create ledger at test-ledger: blockstore error
```

Comment: check this link and installation guide for windows users
https://learn.figment.io/tutorials/setup-the-project

Comment: I found a similar answer here, it work for me,check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70314459/solana-start-solana-test-validator-on-linux-ubuntu-blockstore-error

Answer (score 2):

This is a current annoyance with natively using Windows with `solana-test-validator`.  It shells out to `tar` with `bzip2`, which isn't available in the default Windows shell.

As a workaround, try installing Git BASH and then running `solana-test-validator` from a Git BASH shell.

Source code for the issue can be found at: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/f1e2598baa80a0ad4e8450c8b5e3c5ab164f501c/ledger/src/blockstore.rs#L3789-L3814 -- the `j` flag indicates to use `bzip2`